# How do I refer to the collection from inside an enumerator method?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have an array:

```
arr = [53, 55, 51, 60]
```

Now I call some enumeration method on it. Stripped down example:

```
arr.each_with_index { |e, i| puts "Element #{i} of #{arr.length} is #{e}" }
#=> Element 0 of 4 is 53
#=> Element 1 of 4 is 55
#=> Element 2 of 4 is 51
#=> Element 3 of 4 is 60
```

If I change that to:

```
[1, 10, 100].each_with_index {|e, i| puts "Element #{i} of #{arr.length} is #{e}" }
#=> Element 0 of 4 is 1
#=> Element 1 of 4 is 10
#=> Element 2 of 4 is 100
```

Which is wrong, since `arr` is still referencing the outer variable.

Is there a way to refer back to the collection from within an enumerator method?

Comment: In lambda? `-> x { x.each_with_index {|e,i| puts "Element #{i} of #{x.length} is #{e}" } }.([1,10,100])` I'm also wondering `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-tap), although it does return the original array too:

```
[1, 10, 100].tap { |arr|
  arr.each.with_index(1) { |e,i| puts "Element #{i} of #{arr.size} is #{e}" }
}
#=> [1, 10, 100]
```

prints:

```
Element 1 of 3 is 1
Element 2 of 3 is 10
Element 3 of 3 is 100
```

Here we pass `[1, 10, 100]` to `tap`'s block where it's represented by `arr`, then we do what we need. Also note I've used `each.with_index(1)` instead of `each_with_index`. This allows us to offset the counter `i` to start at `1` instead of the default `0`. Relevant for your example.

Comment: I was playing with `.tap` but had not quite gotten it to the same terms as the example. Thanks.